# Why jsonSerialization config value must be divisible by 1024?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I was searching how to update the maximum json serialization size in web.config, and I have found this famous post: [Can I set an unlimited length for maxJsonLength in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config/12278956#12278956)

What I would like to ask is, under the accepted answer, there are comments about the maximum size: 2147483647 vs 2147483644

And one of the comments said they are practically the same ***because 2147483644 is the maximum integer divisible by 1024 in range***.

Does that mean, jsonSerialization attribute value must always be divisible 1024? For example if I set it to 1025, 1026...2047, is it the same as setting it to 1024? And why is it so?

Comment: I'd guess its something to do with byte allocation in memory.

Comment: @AshleyMedway I think so, but I can't find any documents supporting this, I do not even know is the claim in that comment is true...